# what kind of Machine Learning algorithm Fitbit might be using to determine how much user has slept?

Tags: android, machine-learning, time-series, fitbit, sleep-mode

So a wearable device like Fitbit has data from accelerometer( movements in the wearable(watch) ) and also heart rate depending upon the device. 
And using the data from these inputs, fitbit is able to predict how much user has slept. 
So data I have looks like :

```
Time              |Screen | Mobile_state | Plugged/Unplugged| 

10PM    - 10:30PM | ON    |  Moving      |  Unplugged       
11PM    - 11:15PM | ON    |  Moving      |  Plugged         
11:15PM - 11:51PM | OFF   |  Idle        |  Plugged         
11:51PM - 6:00AM  | OFF   |  Idle        |  Plugged         
6AM     - 6:10AM  | ON    |  Idle        |  UnPlugged       
6:10AM  - 8:00AM  | OFF   |  Idle        |  UnPlugged
```

So here I have 3 parameters, using which i can say user slept from 11:15 till 6AM.
In reality i may have 5-6 params like these. 
What kind of ML algorithm might be useful here which takes this kind of input and gives (11:15PM,6AM) as the output

Comment: Why use machine learning. Not moving and heart rate should for more than lets say 1h should be a quite good indicator for being asleep. Likely times when 'normal' people sleep (= at night) should even improve this prediction.

Comment: How does it differentiate between simply idle and charging vs sleeping? Are you wearing it to sleep? It tracks heart rate too, right?

Comment: @cricket_007 There's a strong assumption, that if mobile is idle in night for large duration, user must be on bed and sleeping. Hence calling it sleep/bed time. It doesn't track heart rate.

Comment: @MrSmith42 I am just thinking if we could do it using ML. We don't have heart rate here as this is just a normal smart phone like Android or iPhone. 
Right now I have written 3 parameters here (Screen, Mobile_state, Plugged). In real, we will have few more and making rules based on all of parameters could be difficult.